# How to really reset an editText in order to show a modified hint

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I want to reset an edit text. I have tried getText().clear() but hint does not appear. Set to "" is not my goal because the listener triggers again. My goal is only to have display hint again. How to ?

**FINAL EDIT question:** the final goal is to replace a character by another character so I thinked about using hint. But in fact, there is a better solution. See my answer below, or a more beautifull solution with Sinner of the System's answer.

**OLD EDIT 1 :**

```
  override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
            var hintSave:String=PKd.text.toString().replace(".","+")
            if (!PKd.text.isNullOrEmpty()){
            Handler().postDelayed({
            PKf.setText("Pkf")
                PKd.setText("")
                PKd.hint=hintSave
            }, 3000)}
        }
```

**OLD EDIT 2 :**

The hint don't appear in one way what is a problem. Can we delay the input into to take account input only one time ?

Comment: just set the text to null and ignore null values in your listener

Comment: Thank you. It does work but the hint appear as I am entering text, letter by letter. is there a possibility to take input into account after a delay ? (see my code in the edited post).

Comment: i don't understand what you want to do

Comment: When I enter 160.080, for instance, I want to have in the edit text 160+080 in the hint. The problem is the hint is displaying not in one ony time. The display change to 1 then 16 then 160 then 160+ etc... It is a problem for me. It is because the listener is triggered each time. is it possible to delay the triggering of the listener ?

Comment: we have no clue what are PKd & PKf .. I think PKd is the EditText ?

Comment: Pkd is an editText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same as your answer but more kotlin styled

```
val Pkd = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTexT_PKd)
val regex = Regex("[.,]")
Pkd.doAfterTextChanged {
    if (it?.contains(regex) == true) {
        Pkd.setText(it.replace(regex, "+"))
        Pkd.setSelection(it.length)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but it is not that I want. I have found the solution. I'ill put the answer.

Comment: i give you other answer

Comment: Great ! Very usefull answer. Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of my problem which was to replace a character to another charater in editText when entering a value. Here, i wanted to replace ',' or '.' by '+'.

**CODE SOLUTION :**

```
val PKd = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTexT_PKd)
        PKd.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

            override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
                PKd.setSelection(editable?.length!!)
            }


            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                PKd.removeTextChangedListener(this)
                PKd.setText(PKd.text.toString().replace(",", "+").replace(".", "+"))
                PKd.addTextChangedListener(this)

            }
        })
```